# C++ respawn function

Tags: c++, arrays, shapes, spawn, tetris

I want when the x equal to 19 to fill that position by this character * and respawn another character * as the tetris game, my approach doesn't work because I reset the x to 1 but the position x=19 and y=10 not filled with this character *.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

char arr[20][20];

int x = 1;

int y = 10;

void spawn()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
        arr[i][j] = '#';
        arr[x][y] = '*';
        }
    }
}

void draw()
{

    spawn();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
        cout << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


void respawn()

{

    if (x == 19) x = 1;
}

int main()
{

    while (true)
    {
        draw();
        sleep(1);
        x++;
        respawn();
        system("cls");
    }
    return 0;}
```

Comment: Perhaps your problem is that you're assuming that C++ uses _column major order_ for the arrays? It doesn't. It uses [row major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) so, you should swap `x` and `y` and use `arr[y][x]` (which would make the `*` wander off to the right instead)

Comment: Btw, why do you expect `x=19` and `y=10` to be filled with `*`? You do `x++` and then immediately call `respawn()` which sets `x=1;` if `x==19` so there's no drawing done when `x==19`. Also note that if you fill the rightmost column (`19`), you should probably also fill the leftmost column (`0`).

Comment: You set `arr[x][y] = '*';` 400 times for fixed values of `x` and `y`. What for? Your `spawn` fills the whole board with `#` and the one at x, y with `*`. You're getting exactly what you've written. What you need is an array that will hold the **state** of the game. You will display your characters based on this array.  No more erasing the board with each `spawn`.